# Run Cocos2d-x Hello World Project on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x

I want to run cocos2d-x  Hello World Project on Windows Phone, but I have no idea how to do it.Currently , I am working on Mac, create cocos2d-x Project and run on iOS Device, its easily achieved. Now, I want to run it on Windows Phone: I am trying some steps but failed:

1. Copy whole project and paste into windows 10 laptop.
2. Try to open .sln file from HelloWorld Project in visual studio but this gives Unsupported Project.

Please give me any hint , how to do it.

Comment: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_Run_cpp-tests_on_WP8

Answer (score 0):

you can copy or create a new project it doesn't matter what dose matter is that you have to open the proj.win8.1-universal folder in visual studio then open up the *.sln file and you have to have a community version of visual studio which has by default the wp8.1 sdk that allows you to open an develop wp8.1 projects and 2013 or 2015 will do just fin.